# How to set material ui time picker dilog styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am integrating [material ui time picker](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-time-picker)

I need to change the color of time

[image]

You can see in the image. I need to change the color of `11:30 pm`. And also I need to change width and height of the dilog box.

I tried this but didn't work

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#efbb40'
    }
  },
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
    suppressDeprecationWarnings: true
  }
})
```

I searched a lot but couldn't able do it.

Please help!!!

Comment: It's a little complex here.Could you provide a codesandbox?That I can show it to you.

Comment: @Root I don't know how to create sandbox. I just copy paste code from [here](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-time-picker). Please post as an answer what you are trying to show.

Comment: @Root Could you answer please?

Comment: I have answered it.And just an option.Hope to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read the original code of time picker in node_modules.The style in it is defined different from material-ui.So I offer an option to override them here.

First,copy the code in node_modules/material-ui-time-picker/lib/TimePicker.js to a TimePicker.js.And remember to change the following two part.

```
var _Clock = require('material-ui-time-picker/lib/Clock');
var _util = require('material-ui-time-picker/lib/util');
```

Second,import the TimePicker from your TimePicker.js not from node_modules

```
import TimePicker from './TimePicker'

                <Button
                    onClick={() => this.setState({ open: true })}
                >
                    Open time picker
                </Button>
                <Dialog
                    maxWidth='xs'
                    open={this.state.open}
                >
                    <TimePicker/>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ open: false })} color='primary'>
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ open: false })} color='primary'>
                            Ok
                        </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
```

Then, you will get the same TimePicker now.And you can feel free to change the style in TimePicker.js